# Shellscript: Comparing parameters, outputting max and min

Tags: bash, shell

Now as I am fairly new to shell scripting and Linux itself, I am quite confused as to why this does not work. An explanation along with the answer would be great help since I really want to learn this. Anyways here is my code:

```
      #!/bin/bash
      #
      #Script number 7
      #
      while i in $#;
      do
         if [ $i -gt $@ ]; then max=$i; fi
         if [ $i -lt $@ ]; then min=$i; fi
      done
      echo Max is: $max
      echo Min is: $min
```

What I need to do is obtain a list of parameters then compare them and output the ones with the highest and least value. I feel like I am missing something completely here. Based on my loop I look for the value that is greater than the list and assign it as max. Then I look for the least and assign it as min. Any help is wonderful. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you really want to learn what/how your script is working, use `set -vx` to debug/trace the activity. A little confusing at first, the shell first displays the next statement (group) that will be evaluated, in your case, it will show the whole while loop, THEN it will show each cmd as it is executed (preceded by a '+' sign). Good luck.

Comment: This helps a lot for actually finding out what is going wrong. Thanks!

Comment: A shell is an environment from which to call tools and manipulate files and processes. It has some programming constructs to allow you to sequence those tasks. That's all. Don't try to write programs like this in shell as that's not what it's designed for so it's relative ill-equipped to do it. There's better-suited tools out there such as awk, perl, ruby, etc. and awk comes standard with every UNIX installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is a little off, please see the following example:

```
#!/bin/bash


List=(-3 1 2 3 4 5);
max=-999999999;
min=999999999;

  for i in ${List[@]}
  do
     if [[ $i -gt $max ]] 
     then 
         max=$i
     fi
     if [ $i -lt $min ] 
     then
        min=$i
     fi
  done

echo Max is: $max
echo Min is: $min
```

Your output should be:

```
Max is: 5
Min is: -3
```

Comment: What if the lowest isn't less than zero?

Comment: Just fixing his example, not trying to create some world's best script. There are a million ways to do this, I was just trying to set him down the right path in which they would discover the problems inherent in their original idea.

Answer (score 4):

The answer you picked isn't going to do it. If there is no negative number, that won't work. Try that with list as `3`, `4`, and `5`. That will give you that the minimum is zero.

What you need to do is to set both minimum and maximum to the first number in the list, then go through the rest of the numbers to get it:

```
#! /bin/bash

min=$1
max=$1
shift

for num in $@
do
    [ $num -gt $max ] && max=$num
    [ $num -lt $min ] && min=$num
done

echo "Min = $min  Max = $max"
```

I set both `min` and `max` to the first number in my list. I then use `shift` to get rid of that number.

Now, I go through each number in my list. The `$@` represents the command line arguments. Both  `$@` and `$*` represent all of the positional parameters, and either will work in this case.

The

```
[ $num -gt $max ] && max=$num
```

statement is similar to

```
if [ $num -gt $@ ]; then max=$num; fi
```

which is similar to how you put your `if` statement on a single line. However, the way I did it is a standard way it's done in BASH. The `&&` is a list operator. If the statement before the `&&` is true, the statement after the `&&` will be executed. Otherwise, the statement after the `&&` won't be executed.

You'll see a similar thing with the `||` list operator. This is an inverse where the statement after the `||` is only executed if the statement before is false.

It looks like the special variables were confusing to you:

- `while` *`statement`*: This will continue to loop as long as *`statement`* continues to return a *true* value. In shell, a true value is zero, and a false value is non-zero.
- `$#` is the number of command line parameters with `$1 to $x` representing each parameter.
- `$@` represents a list of all command line parameters.
- `for` *`var`* in *`list`*: This sets the variable *`var`* to each item in the *`list`*. This is usually what you want when you parse command line parameters.

Answer (score 0):

This is a job for awk, not shell:

```
$ cat tst.sh
awk -v argsS="$*" 'BEGIN {

    numArgs = split(argsS,argsA)
    min = max = argsA[1]

    for (idx=2; idx<=numArgs; idx++) {
        arg = argsA[idx]
        min = (arg < min ? arg : min)
        max = (arg > max ? arg : max)
    }

    print "min=",min
    print "max=",max

}'

$ ./tst.sh 3 8 2 9 4
min= 2
max= 9

$ ./tst.sh the quick brown fox jumped        
min= brown
max= the

$ ./tst.sh 3                         
min= 3
max= 3

$ ./tst.sh -2 -5 -1
min= -5
max= -1
```

Notice that it works with strings as well as numbers, it can be trivially customized to print "NaN' or whatever you like if invalid input is provided, and it won't incorrectly print "0" as the max value when all of your input numbers are negative or zero as the min when you only provide 1 positive number (try both of those test cases on the shell solution you selected as the right answer).

Comment: Shell can handle this quite nicely, and with all builtin functions too.

Comment: Great, please post the equivalent portable shell script. I'm particularly interested in seeing how it handles strings.

Answer (score 0):

I'm joining the party.

```
#!/bin/bash
{ read min; read max; } <<< "$(printf "%s\n" "$@" | sort -n | sed -n '1p;$p')"
echo "Min: $min, Max: $max"
```